# A sum involving roots of unity

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, cv.complex-variables, cyclotomic-fields

Let $n$ be a positive integer and $\zeta$ be a primitive $n$th root of unity. It is not hard to show that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{\zeta^k}{1-\zeta^k}=\frac{1-n}{2}.
\end{align*}
Since $\zeta^n=1$, we have
\begin{align*}
\frac{\zeta^k}{1-\zeta^k}+\frac{\zeta^{n-k}}{1-\zeta^{n-k}}
=\frac{\zeta^k}{1-\zeta^k}+\frac{\zeta^{-k}}{1-\zeta^{-k}}
=-1,
\end{align*}
and so
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{\zeta^k}{1-\zeta^k}=\frac{1}{2}
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(\frac{\zeta^k}{1-\zeta^k}+\frac{\zeta^{-k}}{1-\zeta^{-k}}\right)
=\frac{1-n}{2}.
\end{align*}
Let $\omega$ be a primitive $(3n+2)$th root of unity. By the same method, we can also get
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{2n+1}(-1)^k\omega^{\frac{k(3k+1)}{2}}=
\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left((-1)^k\omega^{\frac{k(3k+1)}{2}}+(-1)^{2n+1-k}
\omega^{\frac{(2n+1-k)(3(2n+1-k)+1)}{2}}\right)=0,
\end{align*}
because
\begin{align*}
\omega^{\frac{(2n+1-k)(3(2n+1-k)+1)}{2}}=\omega^{\frac{k(3k+1)}{2}+(3n+2)(2n-2k+1)}=
\omega^{\frac{k(3k+1)}{2}}.
\end{align*}
Note that the above two sums possess natural symmetries.

**Question.**
Let $\omega=e^\frac{2\pi i}{3n+2}$ be the primitive $(3n+2)$th root of unity.
Numerical calculation suggests that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1}\frac{(-1)^k\omega^{\frac{k(3k+1)}{2}}}{1-\omega^{3k}}=-\frac{n+1}{2}.
\end{align*}
Is this identity true? If so, how to prove it?
Unfortunately, this sum loses a natural symmetry.
Hints, references or proofs are all welcome!

**Comments:**
Nemo proved that for arbitrary $w$,
\begin{align*}
\sum _{k=1}^{2 n+1} \frac{(-1)^k w^{k (3 k+1)/2}}{1-w^{3 k}}&=-\sum _{k=0}^{2 n} \frac{(-1)^k w^{\frac{1}{2} (k+2) (3 k+1)}}{1-w^{3 k+1}}\\
&+\frac{1}{2} \sum _{k=0}^{2 n} \left(\frac{(-1)^k w^{(3 k+1) (n+1)}}{1-w^{(3k+1)/2}}+\frac{w^{(3 k+1) (n+1)}}{w^{(3k+1)/2}+1}\right)\\
&+\frac{1}{2} \sum _{k=1}^{2 n+1} \left(\frac{(-1)^k w^{k/2}}{1-w^{3k/2}}+\frac{w^{k/2}}{w^{3k/2}+1}\right).
\end{align*}
This identity has been reproved by GH from MO below.

Letting $k\to 2n+1-k$ in the following sum gives
\begin{align*}
\sum _{k=0}^{2 n} \frac{(-1)^k w^{\frac{1}{2} (k+2) (3 k+1)}}{1-w^{3 k+1}}
=\sum _{k=1}^{2 n+1} \frac{(-1)^k w^{k (3 k+1)/2}}{1-w^{3 k}},
\end{align*}
where we have used the fact $w^{3n+2}=1$. Also, we have (letting $k\to 2n+1-k$)
\begin{align*}
 \sum _{k=0}^{2 n} \left(\frac{(-1)^k w^{(3 k+1) (n+1)}}{1-w^{(3k+1)/2}}+\frac{w^{(3 k+1) (n+1)}}{w^{(3k+1)/2}+1}\right)=
 \sum _{k=1}^{2 n+1} \left(\frac{(-1)^k w^{k/2}}{1-w^{3k/2}}+\frac{w^{k/2}}{w^{3k/2}+1}\right).
\end{align*}
So it suffices to show that 
\begin{align*}
\sum _{k=1}^{2 n+1} \left(\frac{(-1)^k w^{k/2}}{1-w^{3k/2}}+\frac{w^{k/2}}{w^{3k/2}+1}\right)=-n-1,
\end{align*}
which was proved by Fedor Petrov.

Comment: This reminds me of [Daniel Shanks, *A short proof of an identity of Euler*](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1951-002-05/S0002-9939-1951-0043808-6/) (if not for the denominators on the left hand side...). Wondering if there is anything behind this?

Comment: Can you prove at least that your sum is rational? If so, you can average it over all primitive roots of unity of degree 3n+2.

Comment: @Seva, It seems to be difficult to prove this sum is real.

Comment: It looks like a "q-version" (whatever this means) of the known congruence $1-1/2+1/3-1/4+\dots+1/(2n+1)\equiv 0 \pmod {3n+2}$ provided that $3n+2$ is prime. (For $n=659$ this was proposed on IMO in year $3n+2=1979$.) The standard solution is $S=(1+1/2+\dots+1/(2n+1))-2(1/2+\dots+1/(2n))=1/(n+1)+\dots+1/(2n+1)$ and now the symmetry $1/x+1/(3n+2-x)\equiv 0 \pmod {3n+2}$. I do not see how to modify it.

Comment: I proved $$\sum _{k=1}^{2 n+1} \frac{(-1)^k w^{k (3 k+1)/2}}{1-w^{3 k}}=-\sum _{k=0}^{2 n} \frac{(-1)^k w^{\frac{1}{2} (k+2) (3 k+1)}}{1-w^{3 k+1}}+\\\frac{1}{2} \sum _{k=0}^{2 n} \frac{(-1)^k w^{(3 k+1) (n+1)}}{1-w^{(3k+1)/2}}+\frac{1}{2} \sum _{k=0}^{2 n} \frac{w^{(3 k+1) (n+1)}}{w^{(3k+1)/2}+1}+\frac{1}{2} \sum _{k=1}^{2 n+1} \left(\frac{(-1)^k w^{k/2}}{1-w^{3k/2}}+\frac{w^{k/2}}{w^{3k/2}+1}\right)$$ for arbitrary $w$.

Comment: Now if one specifies w as the primitive (3n+2)th root of unity then the first sum on the rhs due to the symmetry $k\to 2n+1-k$ equals the sum under consideration $$\sum _{k=1}^{2 n+1} \frac{(-1)^k w^{k (3 k+1)/2}}{1-w^{3 k}}=\sum _{k=0}^{2 n} \frac{(-1)^k w^{\frac{1}{2} (k+2) (3 k+1)}}{1-w^{3 k+1}}$$ thus allows to solve for this sum in terms of 4 simpler sums. I believe this 4 simple sums can be calculated using the symmetry $k\to 2n+1-k$.

Comment: Based on the comments from @Nemo, it suffices to show that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1}\left(\frac{(-y)^k}{1-y^{3k}}+
\frac{y^{k}}{1+y^{3k}}\right)=-n-1,
$$
where $y=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{6n+4}}$ is the primitive $(6n+4)$th root of unity.

Comment: I added a proof of Nemo's identity. The whole thing is mysterious and beautiful!

Comment: Please update your post: Nemo's identity is proved in my answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the proof of Kevin Liu's version 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1}\left(\frac{(-y)^k}{1-y^{3k}}+ \frac{y^{k}}{1+y^{3k}}\right)=-n-1
$$
(for the primitive root of unity $y$ of degree $6n+4$) of Nemo's reduction. (Both reductions deserve to be explained, in my opinion.)

We have $$\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1} \frac{(-y)^k}{1-y^{3k}}=
-\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1} \frac{y^{k}}{1-y^{3k}}+2\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{y^{2k}}{1-y^{6k}}.$$

So we should prove

$$2\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1} \frac{y^{4k}}{1-y^{6k}}-2\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{y^{2k}}{1-y^{6k}}=n+1$$

Denote again $w=y^2$, the primitive root of unity of degree $3n+2$, this reads as

$$
2\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1}\frac{w^{2k}}{1-w^{3k}}-2\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{w^k}{1-w^{3k}}=n+1
$$

Partition LHS onto two identical halfs (it has multiple 2 for that), and in one of them make the change of variables $k\mapsto 3n+2-k$. This half reads as 
$$
\sum_{k=n+1}^{3n+1}\frac{w^{-2k}}{1-w^{-3k}}-\sum_{k={2n+2}}^{3n+1}\frac{w^{-k}}{1-w^{-3k}}=
-\sum_{k=n+1}^{3n+1}\frac{w^{k}}{1-w^{3k}}+\sum_{k={2n+2}}^{3n+1}\frac{w^{2k}}{1-w^{3k}}.
$$
Collecting with another half we get (so lucky)
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{3n+1} \frac{w^{2k}-w^k}{1-w^{3k}}=-\sum_{k=1}^{3n+1} w^k\frac{1-w^{3k(n+1)}}{1-w^{3k}}=
-\sum_{k=1}^{3n+1} (w^k+w^{4k}+w^{7k}+\dots+w^{(3n+1)k})=n+1,
$$
since the numbers $1,4,\dots,3n+1$ are not divisible by $3n+2$ and $\sum_{k=0}^{3n+1} w^{kd}=0$ for all integers $d$ non-divisible by $3n+2$.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a proof of Nemo's identity. Using the notation $y:=w^{1/2}$, multiplying both sides by $2$, and shifting $k$ by $1$ in three of the five sums, the identity can be rewritten as
$$\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1}f_{k,n}(y)=0,$$
where
\begin{align*}f_{k,n}(y):=&\frac{(-1)^ky^k}{1-y^{3k}}+\frac{y^k}{1+y^{3k}}-2\frac{(-1)^ky^{k(3k+1)}}{1-y^{6k}}\\[6pt]
&+2\frac{(-1)^ky^{(k+1)(3k-2)}}{1-y^{6k-4}}-\frac{(-1)^ky^{(2n+2)(3k-2)}}{1-y^{3k-2}}
+\frac{y^{(2n+2)(3k-2)}}{1+y^{3k-2}}\\[6pt]
=&(-1)^ky^k\frac{1-y^{3k^2}}{1-y^{3k}}+y^k\frac{1-(-1)^ky^{3k^2}}{1+y^{3k}}\\[6pt]
&+(-1)^ky^{(k+1)(3k-2)}\frac{1-y^{(2n-k+1)(3k-2)}}{1-y^{3k-2}}
+(-1)^ky^{(k+1)(3k-2)}\frac{1+(-1)^ky^{(2n-k+1)(3k-2)}}{1+y^{3k-2}}\\[6pt]
=&\sum_{m=0}^{k-1}\left((-1)^k+(-1)^m\right)y^{k(3m+1)}+
\sum_{m=0}^{2n-k}\left((-1)^k+(-1)^{k+m}\right)y^{(k+m+1)(3k-2)}.
\end{align*}
In the first $m$-sum, the term $m=k-1$ does not contribute, hence what we really need to prove is
$$\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1}\sum_{m=0}^{k-2}\left((-1)^k+(-1)^m\right)y^{k(3m+1)}+
\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1}\sum_{m=0}^{2n-k}\left((-1)^k+(-1)^{k+m}\right)y^{(k+m+1)(3k-2)}
=0.$$
In the second double sum, we make the change of variables $k':=k+m+1$ and $m':=k-1$. With this notation, the previous equation becomes
$$\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1}\sum_{m=0}^{k-2}\left((-1)^k+(-1)^m\right)y^{k(3m+1)}+
\sum_{k'=1}^{2n+1}\sum_{m'=0}^{k'-2}\left((-1)^{m'+1}+(-1)^{k'-1}\right)y^{k'(3m'+1)}
=0.$$
The two double sums now clearly neutralize each other termwise, and the proof is complete.